# Segmentation fault in array of linked lists

Tags: c, arrays

I'm tryin to create an array of linked lists and have run into a problem with just the array. The code runs fine(or at least printf runs in the function) but when I try to loops through in main to print I get a segmentation fault and the lines don't print in the newLabel function.

```
void newLabel(char *n, Label **p, int len) {
  p[len] = malloc(sizeof(Label));
  p[len]->next = NULL;
  p[len]->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(n)+1);
  strcpy(p[len]->name, n);
  printf("%s", p[len]->name);
  ++labels;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  Label *p[100];
  for (labels = 0; labels < 5; labels++) {
    newLabel("Hi", p, labels);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i <= labels; i++) {
    printf("%s", p[labels]->name);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just run it in debugger

Comment: I guess because the string goes into to the name field of Label and the function is specific to Label. But I suppose you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  for (labels = 0; labels < 5; labels++) {
    newLabel("Hi", p, labels);
  }
```

In this loop you allocated first 5 elements of `*p`

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= labels; i++) {
    printf("%s", p[labels]->name);
  }
```

I this next loop you are accessing 6th member which has not been allocated

Comment: That's just a mistake from moving it out of the main program. It still doesn't work when fixing that. I moved it out because putting the print loop in someone breaks the newLabel function. It doesn't print all the names as it does when the for loop is commented out.

Comment: is labels global? if yes its being incremented twice, just make is local to main() and run the print loop same as the first loop eg for (int i = 0; i < labels; i++) {
    printf("%s", p[i]->name);
  }

Comment: Yeah, that was issue. Same in the original except in different function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out your code

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= labels; i++) { //problem here 
    printf("%s", p[labels]->name);
  }
```

you are execute a loop start from 0 to labels(5). it means it run for labels value 0,1,2,3,4,5 i.e 6 times while you are allocate memory for only 5 elements in below code

```
for (labels = 0; labels < 5; labels++) {
    newLabel("Hi", p, labels);
  }
```

solution is remove = from for loop i.e for loop syntax is

```
for (int i = 0; i < labels; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

By the end of this loop here

```
for (labels = 0; labels < 5; labels++) {
    newLabel("Hi", p, labels);
  }
```

`labels` is 5 which is never initialized, yet in below loop you are still  trying to print `p[5]`

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= labels; i++) {
    printf("%s", p[labels]->name); // this labels can be 5 here
  }
```

So loop within boundaries

```
for (int i = 0; i < labels; i++) {
    printf("%s", p[labels]->name);
  }
```